# Sharepoint development deployment problems

Tags: c#, sharepoint, visual-studio-2012, sharepoint-2013

I am getting the following error, when trying to deploy the visual studio generated Blank Sharepoint Project.

> Error 1   Error occurred in deployment step 'Retract Solution': Cannot
>   connect to the SharePoint site: `http://srv-sharepoint:35018/`. Make
>   sure that this is a valid URL and the SharePoint site is running on
>   the local computer. If you moved this project to a new computer or if
>   the URL of the SharePoint site has changed since you created the
>   project, update the Site URL property of the project.

I set up a new application so have these 3 now: (Name, URL, Port)

> SharePoint - 80     `http://srv-sharepoint/`    80
>
> SharePoint Central Administration v4     `http://srv-sharepoint:32152/`    32152
>
> SharePoint - Test     `http://srv-sharepoint:35018/`    35018

Its all on the server. And my project URL is `http://srv-sharepoint:35018/`

When I changed it to the admin port, it "ran" but just loaded up the admin panel.

What Am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Add the current user to the web content database with owner role ([more](http://mushannak.blogspot.ru/2013/02/error-occurred-in-deployment-step.html#sthash.ODKzDKXi.dpuf)).

Answer (score 0):

Have you setup the hostname ("srv-sharepoint") in your network's DNS or your machines hosts-file?

To setup your local development environment to use the "srv-sharepoint" host name, you need to add the host name to your development machine's hosts file.

The file is located at "C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts" and you need to add an entry like this "127.0.0.1 srv-sharepoint". Note that this requires administrative privileges.

You may have to disable the loopback check as well, nut I honestly can't remember if that is necessary. See [this link](http://blogs.technet.com/b/sharepoint_foxhole/archive/2010/06/21/disableloopbackcheck-lets-do-it-the-right-way.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

1.Check the web url in properties of the solution is valid.
(or)
2. Confirm the status of **"Sharepoint timer service"** is active/running.
(or)
3. It may due to the error occurred in previous deployment process of the same solution. So go to the **central admin** --> **System Settings** --> **Manage Farm Solutions**. Find out the solution, open it and retract the solution manually. Once retraction is completed, remove it. Then try again to deploy it using your IDE, visual studio, as administrator.

Answer (score 0):

Your site url may be incorrect in solution, check it as below.
1) select the project, hit f4, properties of solution will open.
2) check the deployment url in project properties.
3) update the url as per the local url.
4) save, rebuild and deploy.

It should work.